# How to calculate age from given data on input field?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, jquery-ui

I have searched but i didn't get perfect solution of my issue.I can calculate age in normal way.But i haven't any idea how can i calculate age from given data on input field.I have used **[jQuery DatePicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)** for input field.My code:

```
$birthday = new DateTime('1970-02-01');
$to       = new DateTime('today');
echo $birthday ->diff($to)->y.' Years, '.$birthday ->diff($to)->m.' Months, '.$birthday ->diff($to)->d.' Days ';
```

This is my field:

[image]

Now i want `$birthday` will be dynamic and it will insert and want to show immediately age calculation without page load. Have any clue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to calculate the age in jQuery, you can use [`moment.js`](http://momentjs.com/) like this:

```
moment("05/05/1998", "MM/DD/YYYY").month(0).from(moment().month(0));
// Output = 22 years ago
```

```js
$(function() {
  var dob = $('.dob').val();
  $('.dob').on('input', function(e) {
    var a = moment($(this).val(), "MM/DD/YYYY").month(0).from(moment().month(0))
    console.log(a);
  });
  var a = moment($('.dob').val(), "MM/DD/YYYY").month(0).from(moment().month(0))
  console.log(a);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.5.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class='dob' type='text' value="05/05/1996">
```

Inside your controller, you can use Carbon's `age` method like this:

```
$birthday = Carbon\Carbon::parse('1970-02-01');
$age = $birthday->age;
// Output - (int) 46
```

> See [Carbon Docs](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-getters) for reference

Hope this helps!

Comment: My problem is not calculate age.I can not get value from input field.If i get the dynamic birthday from input field then i can do this.How can i get this `('1970-02-01');` value from input field?

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery datepicker displays the dates in an input field with `id="datepicker"` that you can use to get your date. For a client-side calculation, the `momentjs` library mentionned in other answer if perfect for this job.

```js
fromdate = $('#datepicker').val();
console.log(fromdate);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="datepicker" class="hasDatepicker" value="2016/14/12">
```

If you want to calculate server-side, you can pass the value to PHP without reloading page with Ajax:

```
$('#datepicker').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "datecalc.php",
        data: {text:$(this).val()}
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for describing. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the value of the data input field using JQuery or Javascript and then pass the value to your age calculation function.

For example if your date field has id="date-picker", then you can read the date as $("date-picker").val() or document.getElementById("date-picker").value()